# How to transform a className to uninstantiated class in >php7.1

Tags: php, php-7

As expected the example below does not work but how can i tell php that my classname-string should be an uninstantiated class  ?
I know that i could work around with some tricks but is there a proper way?

thanks to magnus i like to add that in use I don't want to hard code the class name in the function it could be anything but taking care that it exists etc is not part of the question.

(for php>7.1)

The other direction works with `get_class`.

```
Interface iFoo {
    static function getBar(): string;
}
class Foo implements  iFoo {
    private static $bar = "`My test value`";
    static function getBar(): string {
        return self::$bar;
    }
}

function getMyClass() : iFoo {
    $classes = array('Foo');
    print "this works: ".$classes[0]::getBar();
    // return failes
    print "this does not:";
    return $classes[0];
}
```

Output:

```
this works: `My test value`this does not:

Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of getMyClass() must implement interface iFoo, string returned
```

I know that it works with `: iFoo | string` but then the typehinting is obsolete. I am missing something like a make-class-of-string() function.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: If `: iFoo` could mean either a string or a class instance, it would be useless as a type. Types are used to make sure that you'll always get what you expect from a function/method. If it could return either a string or an object, it would be ambiguous and you wouldn't know if you should use `getMyClass()->foo()` or `getMyClass()::foo()`. Explain what problem you're really trying to solve here and we might be able to help with that. Currently, this sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You can't return an un-instantiated class.

Comment: exactly but i want to force it to be a class object (not an instance of a class) of that type. I would use it to route to a specific implementation of iFoo depending on conditions.

Comment: An object _is_ an instance of a class, so the statement _"force it to be a class object (not an instance of a class) "_ makes no sense. You can either return an _instance_ of a class which either is called iFoo, extends iFoo or implements iFoo. If you want to return a string, use `: string`. If you want to make sure that the string you return is a valid class name that implements a specific interface, you need to validate that in your function before returning the string. You can use [class_implements()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) for that.

Comment: `new className()`  would be an instance   className is a  `class`. I am well aware of what happens here i want to know if there is a syntactic way oŕ a php function making sure that it can only be the `class` so that typehinting works properly

Comment: It's not possible to type hint that a function/method should return a string that refers to a class name, let alone any attributes it should have.

Comment: Ok but is there a solution like casting or some php function to transform the string -> class (thats my question in one sentence)

Comment: If you just want to return an actual object, you can dynamically instantiate the class by doing: `return new $classes[0];`. But since you explicitly say that you don't want to _"force it as an instance of a class"_, I'm not sure that's what you want (unless you actually just mean that you don't want to _hard code_ the class name in the function?) If not, I have no idea what you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it.

The return type is a type of an instance (be it a complex or a primitive type). Something that exists in memory.

The `::class` keyword is a simple helper that resolves to a fully qualified name of a class, which is a string (a primitive type).

A return type is a type of an object and not something that would be of a specific type upon instantiation. And there are no tricks to say "upon instantiation, this string will be of type `Foo`".

The `$classes[0]::getBar()` construct works because it's a syntactic sugar. PHP resolves it to something like `Foo::getBar()` which syntactically is a call to a static function. And as you noticed - that works perfectly fine.